# using header function inside a loop

Tags: php

```
<?php
$a = array('f-stat,porcelain mask'=>'jay azima','jay azima,oil painting'=>'japanese doll');
$msg="We can't recommend any items to you.";
foreach($a as $k=>$v)
{
  if($_GET['items']==$k)
  {
    header("location: hola.php?tequilla=".$v);
  }

}
header("location: hola.php?tequilla=".$msg);
?>
```

What I tried to do is if string from `$_GET['items']` matches any of key in `$a` array, it is redirected to hola.php with `$v` value. Otherwise `$msg string` is passed. But the problem is even if the `$k` and `$_GET['items']` matches, latter header function is executed with `$msg` value. Also if I remove the latter header function, the header function inside the loop works fine.

Comment: You need `exit();` after the `header` lines so the script doesn't continue to run.

Comment: I prefer `die();` ... I can be morbid like that - but it's the same thing.

Comment: Additionaly, you can use `var_dump($_GET['items']);` and `trim()` to make sure you do not have any spaces or to count characters while you are comparing string in your if condition.

Comment: `$_GET['items']==$k` seriously?

Comment: I'm a rookie to coding. What's wrong with $_GET['items']==$k?. Tip me, I can use the help. Thank You. -@u_mulder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `exit()` it stops the execution of the script. This will not redirect to second header.

```
<?php
    $a = array('f-stat,porcelain mask'=>'jay azima','jay azima,oil painting'=>'japanese doll');
    $msg="We can't recommend any items to you.";

    foreach($a as $k=>$v)
    {

      if($_GET['items']==$k)
      {
        header("location: hola.php?tequilla=".$v);
        exit(); // < this will stop the script before the 2nd header()
      }

    }

    header("location: hola.php?tequilla=".$msg);
    exit();

    ?>
```

Comment: the problem persists. Is is even okay to use header function inside the loop? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: This is okay.
Did you checked that $_GET['items']  value matched with $k ?

Comment: yeah.. i made it sure.. :)

Comment: Use **trim** function. May be space comes in your value.

Answer (score 1):

All your code simplified:

```
$a = array(
    'f-stat,porcelain mask'=>'jay azima',
    'jay azima,oil painting'=>'japanese doll'
);
$v = !empty($a[$_GET['items']])? $a[$_GET['items']] : "We can't recommend any items to you.";

header("Location: hola.php?tequilla=" . $v);
die();
```

Comment: Is that extra ';' intentional after the array? The problem persists anyway. :(

Comment: No, I removed it. What is the problem now?

Answer (score 0):

> try this

```
<?php
  $a = array('f-stat,porcelain mask'=>'jay azima','jay azima,oil painting'=>'japanese doll');
  $location = '';
  $msg="We can't recommend any items to you.";
  foreach($a as $k=>$v){
    if($_GET['items']==$k){
       $location = "hola.php?tequilla=".$v;
    }
  }
  if($location != ''){
     $location = "hola.php?tequilla=".$msg;
  }
  header("location: ".$location);
  exit(0);
?>
```

Comment: the problem persists. Is is even okay to use header function inside the loop? Am I doing it wrong?